# Solaris 10 - changing default gateway and netmask

Tags: networking, solaris

We have a Sunfire V240 server with Solaris 10, I need to change the subnetmask and gateway. 
I was able to change the subnetmask and gateway  by editing the files
`/etc/subnetmasks` and `/etc/defaultrouter`. Server was rebooted but the problem is that when server shutdown or rebooted, network won't come up as I have to run this command:

`ifconfig bge0 10.91.3.5 netmask 255.255.252.0 broadcast 10.91.3.255 up`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you mean the /etc/netmasks file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to fix the problem. Checked the logs - dmesg ; 
I changed the default gateway on /etc/resolv.conf
Added  nameserver

Answer (score 5):

Check the file `/etc/hostname.bge0`, the configured IP address could be in there. By default the hostname is listed in that file and the name is looked up in `/etc/inet/hosts`. From the found entry, the IP address is used together with the corresponding netmask from `/etc/inet/netmasks`. If a network entry can not be found, the default for the the class type (A, B or C) is used.

So if you need a different netmask to be used for a class A address (10.X.X.X) you should add the network to `/etc/inet/netmasks` like:

```
10.91.0.0 255.255.252.0
```

Comment: Don't forget to click the checkmark to indicate to the site that this answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To make changes permanent:

Ensure default gateway is configured in `/etc/defaultrouter`

The netmask is configured in `/etc/netmasks`

And `/etc/hostname.bge0` is configured with the static IP address

Comment: I cannot find this /etc/network/interfaces, is this a correct path?

Comment: @Venky Thx `/etc/network/interfaces` doesn't exist.

Comment: yes does not exist